# Buscar registro dependiendo del dígito inicial del ID en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hola a toda la comunidad, mi pregunta es sencilla, espero no sea muy tonta pero ahí va...

Tengo 3 tablas llamadas

`empleados_a` - AUTOINCREMENT EMPIEZA CON 1000

`empleados_b` - AUTOINCREMENT EMPIEZA CON 2000

`empleados_c` - AUTOINCREMENT EMPIEZA CON 3000

las cuales en estructura son exactamente igual, la única diferencia es que su `AUTOINCREMENT` empieza con un numero diferente, como comentario todas las tablas tienen la columna ID...

Bien, ahora lo que quiero es construir una consulta que sea algo así

```
SELECT * 
FROM empleados_a 
OR empleados_b 
OR empleados_c 
WHERE ID = 2000
```

Yo sé que el registro con ID 2000 solo existe en la tabla de `empleados_b`, pero la idea es que mi usuario pueda solo colocar el ID que quiere y la consulta haga magia y consulte en las 3 y me muestre el resultado.

Espero haber sido claro con mi duda...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se puede.. y la estructura de esas tablas suena muy pero muy rara.. y en el futuro los id se van a repetir porque el autonumerico 1000 va a llegar a 2000 algun dia.. queres aclarar porque hiciste algo asi?

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos por qué motivo estás manejando tres tablas que parecen idénticas? ¿Por qué no una sola tabla? Si se justifica tener las tres tablas entonces explícanos cuál es el problema, porque no he logrado entenderlo.

Comment: Pues tu uso actual requiere usar UNION para hacer un `SELECT * from a UNION SELECT * from b...` || Que ese sea el diseño óptimo, eso es otra cosa y todo indica que no lo es.

Comment: A. Cedano el motivo de que sean 3 tablas es que cada una tiene un AUTO_INCREMENT direferente,

Comment: pero se entiende que los auto_increment pueden saltar y cruzarse y no tener nada que ver con el que iniciaste en la tabla no?

Comment: en el caso de porque hice lo de las tablas, querian que los numeros de empleados tuvieran ese diferenciador, te explico guardias de seguridad blancos querian que su numero de empleado fuera 1000 que los guardias de seguridad armados fueran 2000 y que los escoltas fueran 3000 realmente no creo que lleguen a tener mas de 1000 guardias de cada tipo, ya que a duras penas llegan a los 100 en los 3 conceptos... yo propuse otras alternativas pero psss no les agrado y esta fue la unica solucion que se me ocurrio

Comment: Yo usaría un tipo_guardia (otra tabla o al menos una convención en tu sistema) con 1-blanco, 2-armado, 3-escolta y dejaría el ID_tipoguardia en la tabla de empleado, única tabla empleado con un único ID AUTOINCREMENT. Tu aproximación actual no es mantenible fácilmente ni mucho menos escalable a cuando aparezcan más tipos de empleados

Comment: yo habia propuesto concatenar la letra B - de blancos con el ID que se le asignara al registro, A si era armado y E si era escolta y eso les mostrara aunque en la tabla el auto increment fuera solo el numero creciendo...

Comment: Esa tampoco es una buena idea. Te sugiero echarle un ojo a normalización de bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: jonathan ninguna base de datos asegura que el auto_increment vaya de uno en uno.. tranquilamente puede saltar el numero 1000 posiciones o mas. Los auto_increment se usan solo para identificar registros, no deben usarse **nunca** como dato, porque no se puede confiar en ellos. Lo que estas haciendo aca, esta mal. Todos los empleados deben ir en una sola tabla, y si queres manejar las identificaciones lo tenes que hacer manual en otra tabla. y debes indicar el tipo de empleado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer la unión de las 3 tablas y aplicar el where sobre esto.

En MySQL 8.0 o superior, puedes utilizar un CTE:

```
with
Empleados as (
      select * from empleados_a 
union select * from empleados_b
union select * from empleados_c
)
select *
  from Empleados  
 where ID = 2000;
```

En MySQL antiguo, puedes hacerlo con una tabla derivada:

```
select *
  from (      select * from empleados_a 
        union select * from empleados_b
        union select * from empleados_c
       ) Empleados  
 where ID = 2000;
```

Dicho esto, la consulta podría devolver más de un registro, pues no hay garantía de que no tengas ID's duplicados entre diferentes tablas, pues luego de los primeros 1000 registros, la tabla `empleados_a` va a comenzar a *producir* ID's que en tu diseño mental van en la tabla `empleados_b`, y después de 2000, ID's de la tabla `empleados_c`. Caso similar ocurre con la tabla `empleados_b`.

Si no quieres que se repitan coloca un constraint `check` para asegurarte que cada tabla se mantiene dentro de cierto rango, abre más los rangos (1 000 000, 2 000 000 y 3 000 000 son más difíciles de traslapar), o cambia de estrategia.

Comment: creo que esto dara mi solucion !!! voy a probarlo ahora mismo y comento si me funciono

Comment: Yo sé que esta respuesta es técnicamente correcta, pero no deja de sentirse como prestarle un encendedor a alguien que se acaba de bañar en gasolina... :/

Comment: @Alfa, entiendo tu punto. Yo no aprobaría ese diseño, si estuviera bajo mi responsabilidad. Pero eso entra en el terreno de las opiniones. Acá yo estoy pasando un destornillador que apretará el tornillo que me mostraron, y no estoy entrando en discusión si ese tornillo debiera ir en donde lo quieren poner y mucho menos si la máquina a la que se lo van a poner tiene sentido. Eso, de todas maneras, queda algo fuera del alcance del sitio.

Comment: lo se y todos tienen razon, les expondre ese esenario a las personas que me lo solicitaron asi esperado hagan mi vida y mi trabajo mas facil y hagamos las cosas de mejor manera